# What are lightweight lisp dialects that compile to readable js?

Tags: javascript, lisp, scheme, racket

What are lisp dialects that compile to short, readable and modifiable JS, using JS's own types?

Comment: have the Bad Idea Bears come to town? Modifying the compiled output is going to cause you serious pain when you need to maintain it. I'm sure it is possible (e.g. with ClojureScript) but *don't do it if you value your sanity*. You should only modify the original source, and look at the compiled output only if needed for debugging purposes.

Comment: I never said I want to modify it, but compiling to readable JS means it has no/little overhead (ClojureScript has around 12k lines overhead) and you can hope engines are optimized for linguistic JS.

Comment: @Viclib I realise this is years late, but I wrote [eslisp](https://github.com/anko/eslisp) to address this exact problem. Having the mapping to generated JavaScript be obvious and easily editable is a major design priority. No overhead. It's just JavaScript with an S-expression syntax and a macro system. Should I add an answer?

Comment: @Anko yes, go ahead. I could accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an extensive [list](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) of compilers for programming languages that compile to JavaScript, including several Lisp/Scheme dialects. Regarding the "short, readable and modifiable" part, that's a bit subjective ... you can test a couple of the compilers listed, and decide which one works best for you.

From [the "Lisp, Scheme" section](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#lisp-scheme) of the list [with minor formatting changes to the sub-section headers]:

> #### Lisp, Scheme
>
> #### Clojure-like
>
> - [ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript) Clojure to JS, the official version. Supports the majority of Clojure including persistent datastructures.
> - [ClojureJS](https://github.com/kriyative/clojurejs) Subset of Clojure to JS.
> - [Chlorinejs](https://github.com/chlorinejs/chlorine) A fork of ClojureJS with a port of clojure.core library.
> - [wisp](https://github.com/Gozala/wisp) A homoiconic JavaScript dialect with Clojure syntax, S-expressions and macros. Aims to be rich subset of Clojure(Script) that seamlessly interops with both Clojure(Script) and JavaScript. *○*
> - [Scriptjure](https://github.com/arohner/scriptjure) Library for generating JavaScript from Clojure forms.
> - [ki](http://ki-lang.org) Clojure-like syntax, [mori](http://swannodette.github.io/mori/)'s immutable data structures in a few [sweet.js](http://sweetjs.org) macros. Can be intermixed with JavaScript. *○*
>
> #### Scheme-like
>
> - [BiwaScheme](http://www.biwascheme.org/) Scheme(R6RS) in JavaScript
> - [Fargo](https://github.com/jcoglan/fargo) Scheme in JavaScript
> - [Moby Scheme](https://github.com/dyoo/moby-scheme) A Scheme running in JS.
> - [nconc](https://github.com/patrickdlogan/nconc) Scheme interpreter in JavaScript with stack-friendly tail calls and full call/cc
> - [scheme2js](http://www-sop.inria.fr/indes/scheme2js/) Scheme to JavaScript.
> - [Spock](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/spock) A Scheme to JavaScript compiler that uses Henry Baker's Cheney-on-the-MTA compilation strategy
> - [Whalesong](http://hashcollision.org/whalesong/) Racket to JS compiler
>
> #### Other
>
> - [eslisp](https://github.com/anko/eslisp) An S-expression syntax for ECMAScript/JavaScript, with Lisp-like hygienic macros that are just JS functions. Aims to be very close to JS, and highly experimental.
> - [EdgeLisp](https://github.com/manuel/edgelisp) A Lisp in the tradition of Common Lisp
> - [Parenscript](http://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/) Subset of Common Lisp to JS.
> - [Ralph](https://github.com/turbolent/ralph) Lisp-1 dialect that compiles to JavaScript, inspired by Dylan
> - [Oppo](https://github.com/benekastah/oppo) A JavaScripter’s lisp. Inspired by JavaScript, Clojure and CoffeeScript. Compiler built using [Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/docs/).
> - [LispyScript](http://lispyscript.com/) A JavaScript with Lispy syntax and Macros. *○*
> - [Outlet](https://github.com/jlongster/outlet) A simple Lisp that supports CPS and in-browser stepping debugging, and other things. In development.
> - [Hot Cocoa Lisp](https://github.com/olleicua/hcl) A Lisp-like language that compiles to JavaScript. *○*
> - [Sibilant](http://sibilantjs.info) JavaScript with a lisp. *○*
> - [jisp](http://jisp.io/) A JS-native and axiomatic Lisp that focuses on the core ideas of code-as-data, S-expressions, and macros, introducing as few new concepts as possible. *○*

Comment: It does not specify if it's compiled to readable js, though. One has to check one by one.

Comment: If it is readable it is probably well-optimized, because it's not interpreted and probably simpler for the VM.

Answer (score 5):

[Parenscript](http://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/) is pretty lightweight and readable. And you use a superior interactive environment for it with [slime-proxy](https://github.com/3b/slime-proxy).

Comment: ParenScript is a great answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think one of the most advanced is ClojureScript. It a very complet implmentation of clojure that compiles to readable or minified JS.

https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript

Maybe check out this if you want to get started: http://clojurescriptone.com/

Comment: It also has a huge overhead.

Answer (score 2):

[LispyScript](http://lispyscript.com/), [Sibilant](http://sibilantjs.info/#welcome) do it nicely. [Parenscript](http://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/), as suggested by Vsevolod Dyomkin, too, but you need Common Lisp. Óscar López's answer provides a [list](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) of other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The stated design goals of [Wisp](https://github.com/Gozala/wisp) match OP's requirements exactly.

It is Clojure-like but has JS semantics and very little overhead. Great if ClojureScript's approach of preserving Clojure semantics even with the cost of 12k lines of overhead is a bad match for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an esoteric answer, but you can have a Haskell-like lisp compile to JS via a combination of [Lisk](https://github.com/chrisdone/lisk#readme) and [Fay](http://fay-lang.org/).

I, for one, really like the idea of Lisk, but it's not very popular in the Haskell community, let alone maintained. Fay, on the other hand, is moving along quite nicely, and one of its main goals is to compile to readable JS. Both were authored by Chris Done.